# How to create *from 0* a bootable disk partition for windows 10?

Tags: windows, boot

I just cloned a hard drive partition (of Windows 10) to a new hard drive.

The thing is that I did it wrong and I just copied the data part, NOT the boot part. So now I have a new hard drive with a Windows copy with no boot partition.

I tested many tutorials, but the problem is that the bootable part NEVER existed on the new hard drive (so it can't be recovered!).

If someone knows how to create from scratch a new bootable partition for Windows 10. I have many licensed programs and lots and lots of configuration.

And if someone asks I just deleted all the data from the old hard drive (genius!), so I can't copy now the bootable disk partition.

Comment: Can you install Windows on the new drive (that will create the boot sector) then clonde the old disk over the top of that install?

Answer (score 19):

There are general steps in the BCDBoot docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di#repair-the-system-partition

For **UEFI** the partition layout is documented at: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions

1. Create a new "system" partition of approximately 250 MB:

   ```
   DISKPART> create partition efi size=250
   ```
2. Format using FAT32, and assign a temporary drive letter:

   ```
   DISKPART> format quick fs=fat32 label="System"
   DISKPART> assign letter="S"
   ```
3. Install the files needed by Windows boot manager, together with an UEFI NVRAM "boot entry":

   ```
   C:\> bcdboot C:\Windows /s S: /f UEFI
   ```

   (Change "C:" to whatever drive letter is assigned to the OS partition at the moment.)

For **BIOS** the partition layout is documented at: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-biosmbr-based-hard-drive-partitions

1. Create a new "system" partition of approximately 100 MB:

   ```
   DISKPART> create partition primary size=100
   ```
2. Format using NTFS, and assign a temporary drive letter:

   ```
   DISKPART> format quick fs=ntfs label="System"
   DISKPART> assign letter="S"
   ```
3. Set the 'active' or 'bootable' flag for this partition:

   ```
   DISKPART> active
   ```
4. Install a partition boot sector:

   ```
   C:\> bootsect /nt60 S:
   ```
5. Install a compatible MBR boot sector to the whole disk:

   ```
   C:\> bootsect /nt60 S: /mbr
   ```
6. Install the files needed by Windows boot manager:

   ```
   C:\> bcdboot C:\Windows /s S: /f BIOS
   ```

   (Replace `C:\Windows` with the actual path to your Windows installation.)

Comment: "bootsect S: /nt60" could be this command wrong?

Comment: Couldn't *bcdboot* be something other than `C:\Windows` as they currently won't be able to boot?  If they are fixing it from PE (as described in your first link) it *may* be `bcdboot D:\Windows /s S:` depending where it was mounted.  Similarly if fixing from another instance of Windows it would be something other than `C:`.

Comment: im using the windows installer cmd

Comment: C:\> bootsect /nt60 S:
C:\> bootsect /nt60  S: /mbr  --> There was a small error

Comment: But i can't boot actually... i tested the two... and nothing... it says the same message. "Reboot and Select proper Boot Device....". I tested to open to see the other partitions... but seems the system doesn't read it...

Comment: @lx07: Ah yes, I forgot to actually add that part to the post. It has to be a path through which you can access the actual Windows directory (because bcdboot copies the files from there); doesn't matter what drive letter you have for it.

Comment: A little trick I've used for a while (need to check if it's still working): if Windows System partition created as EFI System Partition (`create partition efi size=250`, etc.) and MBR written (`bootsect S: /nt60 /mbr`), while BCDBoot called as `bcdboot C:\Windows /s S: /f ALL` then we'll get dual boot MBR/UEFI OS installation.

Comment: This worked for me! However, I had to switch order of arguments here: C:\> bootsect S: /nt60 changes to C:\> bootsect /nt60 S: and my Windows drive letter was E so in the last step ensure you are using the correct drive.

Comment: @Alqio: Are you saying that your Windows partition is on a different physical disk than the S: "System" partition? The bootsector only cares about finding the latter, it doesn't care about the main OS partition.

Comment: No, I meant that my Windows is not C:, but instead on E:. So in the last command (bcdboot C:\Windows /s S: /f BIOS) I changed the C: drive to E: (bcdboot E:\Windows /s S: /f BIOS)

Comment: These diskpart functions might be helpful if you're doing this on a USB flash drive `list disk` `select disk 1` `clean` `convert GPT`