# Boot configuration data missing, no EFI partition, non-GPT disk

Tags: windows-10, boot, gpt

My computer stopped being able to boot - was working fine for years until now.

I have attempted the normal boot repair, and hit errors.

```
bootrec /fixboot
Element not found.
```

I found the BCD file not exist. Attempting a repair per http://woshub.com/how-to-rebuild-bcd-file-in-windows-10/ worked until I got to the bcdedit import step:

```
bcdedit /import c:\boot\bcd.tmp
The requested system device could not be found.
```

More poking around revealed the following, I don't know if they are applicable:
-The system reserved partition is not marked as reserved
-The disk is not GPT
-mbr2gpt cannot find the OS partition on the disk

I cannot even fresh install Windows, as Win10 will not install on a non-GPT disk.

Any ideas how I can get my computer to boot again?

Answer (score 2):

Use `bcdboot` to rebuild the contents of the system partition. It will copy the static Windows Boot Manager files from the specified Windows installation and will build a new BCD (or update an existing one).

```
bcdboot /v c:\windows
```

If it doesn't detect the system partition automatically, you can use the `/s` option to specify it by drive letter. For more steps see this other thread [about creating a system partition from scratch](https://superuser.com/a/1507645/1686).

Note that "System Reserved" is just the partition's *label,* it doesn't indicate anything about whether the partition is valid or not.

---

Regarding fresh installation, Windows' requirements depend purely on which mode the install medium itself was booted in. If the USB stick was booted in UEFI mode (or if you used e.g. Rufus to create an "UEFI-only" USB stick), it will install the OS for UEFI mode and will require GPT disk for that. And if it was booted in legacy mode, it will expect a MBR disk and will install for legacy mode as well.

Comment: Correction: bcdboot said "boot files successfully created" but no other behavior changes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get windows to install fresh by deleting the partitions on the disk, which I did from the install screen. No boot repair option that I could find worked.