# Create boot EFI files

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi

After I have removed my secondary HDD from my laptop it does not boot to Windows 10 anymore. Looks like I need somehow tell BIOS UEFI boot option. But I can't find any *.EFI files in my main system disc. Where they should be located? Can I somehow create them for my Windows 10 disc?

Comment: Can you show the partitions that _are_ present on the disk?

Comment: If you deleted the UEFI partition or damaged it, you likely have to reinstall Windows 10 to get it back. Windows 10 creates the partitions it needs.

Answer (score 1):

If your system is configured to boot Windows in UEFI style, then there should be a partition on a GPT-partitioned disk, formatted as FAT32, and with a partition type GUID that marks it as an EFI System Partition, or ESP for short. It should be typically sized between 100 and 260 MB. The partition is normally hidden and does not have a drive letter, so its existence may go unnoticed unless you specifically go looking for it in Disk Management.

If you boot from a Windows 10 installation media, there is a "Repair your computer" option on the same screen as the "Install now" button that begins a regular installation process. It should detect the presence of your Windows system partition and attempt to reconstruct the UEFI bootloader.

But be careful: in order to successfully repair a UEFI-style system, **the installer must be booted UEFI-style too**. If the repair process fails, you might have to use some bootable partitioning tools to create an empty partition of suitable size and mark it as an ESP partition first, then re-run the repair process.

Most of the Windows bootloader files on the ESP partition are generic and could simply be copied from another installation. But there is one file named `BCD` which contains information specific to your installation, and it must be reconstructed if lost. The repair process can usually do that automatically.

Windows ties the choice of boot style to the choice of partition table type: if your system disk uses GPT partitioning, then you must boot UEFI-style; if your system disk uses legacy MBR partitioning, then you must boot legacy MBR style.

Answer (score 0):

The `*.EFI` files are in the "EFI System Partition" – which is (almost always) FAT32-formatted and therefore needs to be separate from the NTFS-formatted Windows "C:" partition.

It could be that when you installed Windows, it found an existing EFI System Partition on the "secondary" HDD and just placed all files there – so your "primary" disk ended up *not* having an EFI System Partition at all.

You can create one using any partitioning tool, as long as you set the correct "partition type GUID" (for example, in DISKPART use `create partition efi size=100`). Afterwards, use the `bcdboot` command from within a Windows installation CD/USB to copy fresh *.EFI files from the Windows partition, and to generate the "BCD" configuration used by the Windows boot loader.

The process is described in more detail at:

- Super User – [How to create *from 0* a bootable disk partition for windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1507636/how-to-create-from-0-a-bootable-disk-partition-for-windows-10/1507645#1507645)
- Microsoft – Manufacturing – [UEFI/GPT-based hard drive partitions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions)